# Make bounty description in Help Center a little more clear

Tags: feature-request, bounty, help-center

I feel this paragraph from "How is a bounty awarded?" under [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) is a little bit unclear/incomplete:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

Assuming I understand correctly, "the oldest answer is awarded the bounty" should probably be clarified to "the oldest answer is awarded half the bounty amount". This is implied but not clearly stated.

More importantly, this paragraph leaves me wondering what happens if an existing answer is edited *and* receives at least 2 new upvotes during the bounty period. Does it become eligible for the bounty award or does the author of that question have to post an entirely new answer? Some wording to address this question would be helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the linked question that's a duplicate of this one (since it was asked 14 minutes ago)?

Comment: Does it really matter? An SE employee notices that one and answers it and status-completes it while I vaguely recalled other similar questions on the topic. It would be counter productive to dupe vote the other way around. Any way, have my meta up vote ...

Comment: devuxer, I'm the culprit, didn't search well enough. Then again, I pushed it to be fixed a year later :P

Comment: user1803551, rene, no problem guys, and thanks for the upvotes :)