# Bad wording in the rules for auto-awarding bounties

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, help-center

(Similar, but not the same as [Clarifying bounty auto-award-mechanics in the help-center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302640/clarifying-bounty-auto-award-mechanics-in-the-help-center))

In the page [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) there is a paragraph on auto-awarding bounties reading

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded **half the bounty amount**. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded **the bounty**. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

(emphasis mine) I'm pretty sure that if two or more answers are tied, then the oldest answer gets **half the bounty (amount)**, not the full bounty. Otherwise the rules make little sense.

Can anyone fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Repeating "awarded half the bounty amount" in two sentences right next to each other looks plain weird, so I just changed it to "is chosen" since it's a continuation off the previous sentence.

While in there, I also change "the bounty is not awarded to anyone" to "no bounty is awarded to anyone" to clarify that neither the full amount nor the half amount is being awarded.

Now reads:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Comment: Thanks. While at it, can you look at an [older suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293523/wording-improvement-for-the-create-tag-synonyms-help-page) regarding wording in the help center I had which got no attention?

Comment: I think your edit also addresses [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276254/578411), right?

Comment: @rene I think I just didn't search well enough and this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @user1803551 meh...